# How to determine the difference Onto vs One-to-one?

Tags: functions

I have no clue how to solve for this. How can I prove if a function is either onto or one-to-one in the following example?

Let $S$ be the set of all strings of 0's and 1's, and define $D:S \to \mathbb Z$ as follows: for all $s \in S$

$D(s)$ = the number of 1's in s minus the number of 0's in $s$.

1. Is $D$ one-to-one? Prove or give a counterexample.
2. Is $D$ onto? Prove or give a counterexample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f: A \to B$. Think of $B$ as a slice of toast, and $f$ is a function that smears jam ($A$) on the toast.

If $f$ is onto, then every single bit of the toast ($B$) is covered in at least one layer of delicious jam.

If $f$ is one-to-one, then any bit of the toast that is covered with jam is covered with only one layer of jam.

If a function is one-to-one, there might be some bits of toast that are left dry and flavorless. But any part of toast that is covered is covered with only one layer of jam.

If a function is onto, then the toast is completely covered with jam, but in some places, there might be many, many layers of jam, and hence is very messy to eat!

If a function is bijective (one-to-one and onto), then the toast is perfectly covered with a single, smooth layer of jam, and is quite delicious. This is why analysts like bijective functions.

---

To determine if a function is onto, you must check to see if there is an element in $b \in B$ such that no element in $a\in A$ maps to $b$.

To determine if a function is one-to-one, you must check that if $f(a_1) = b = f(a_2)$, then $a_1 = a_2$.

Comment: Is liking toast and jam enough reason for a +1?

Comment: I couldn't help it.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RIHL-Fpef0

Answer (score 1):

a) consider $D(110)$ and $D(11100)$, for example

b) for any given $z\in\mathbb{N}$, take $s=1\dots 1$ (with $z$ ones)

for any given $-z\in\mathbb{N}$, take $s=0\dots 0$ (with $z$ zeroes)

for $z=0$, well, I'm sure you can do that one yourself... :)

Answer (score 0):

For $D$, consider $D(01)$ and $D(10)$. For $F$, ... you never defined $F$.

Comment: You can suppose that  $F=D$.